# Breakpoint Instruction Executed

Tags: c++, arduino-ide

I was working on a Binary Class that uses Three-State Booleans to create measurable (size-wise) arrays of boolean strings that could be translated into morse code (TRUE = dash, FALSE = dot). I am using Arduino IDE (meaning I can't use anything for the std namespace) and a circuit with LEDs to test the morse code, but I will occasionally use Visual Studio 2022 to help debug issues. The problems started to come when I declared a Binary Object variable, then assigned at a constructor, and then used an overloaded assignment operator. The details Microsoft Visual Studio gave me are:

"A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in ConsoleApplication1.exe."

I copied the error details into my search bar and read other forum posts about this (including one of from here, Stack Overflow). What I found the issue to be was `delete[] triboolList` in the Assignment Operator Overload function.

```
void Binary::operator=(tribool newElement) { //For reference, triboolList is of tribool Type
    //The tribool type is defined as: enum tribool{DELIM=-1, FALSE, TRUE};
    delete[] triboolList; //This is the problematic line
    if (newElement == DELIM) {
        triboolList = new tribool(DELIM);
    }
    else {
        triboolList = new tribool[2];
        triboolList[0] = newElement;
        triboolList[1] = DELIM;
    }
}
```

When I commented out the problematic line, the code began working again. Here is my main function in case anyone was curious:

```
Binary code;

tribool test[5] = { FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,DELIM };
code = Binary(test); //Parameter Construction
std::cout << code << std::endl;
//morse(code); //Functions used in the Arduino IDE that I couldn't port over to Visual Studio
//morse(code);
code = TRUE; //This line causes the Breakpoint Instruction Executed error
code += TRUE; 
code += TRUE;
//morse(code, 1); //Arduino IDE custom function that can't be tested on Visual Studio
std::cout << code << std::endl;
```

I know that getting rid of the problematic line fixes my issues, but I am afraid it is also wasting memory addresses. Are my concerns anything major, or am I just overreacting? (In case anyone was curious, my class does have a destructor that is just `delete[] triboolList;`)

Upon hearing about the rule of 3s, I will also be sharing my Copy Constructor and Copy Assignment Operator:

```
Binary::Binary(const Binary& copyBinary) { //Copy Constructor
    triboolList = new tribool[triLength(copyBinary.triboolList) + 1]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) triLength(copyBinary.triboolList); i++) { 
        triboolList[i] = (const tribool)copyBinary.triboolList[i]; 
    } 
    triboolList[triLength(copyBinary.triboolList)] = DELIM; 
}

Binary& Binary::operator=(const Binary& copyBinary) { //Copy Assignment Operator
    delete[] triboolList;
    triboolList = copyBinary.triboolList;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: *I know that getting rid of the problematic line fixes my issues* -- Instead, it introduces a memory leak.  Does your `Binary` class follow the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I know, that is what I meant by wasting memory addresses. At least I know my concerns were correct, so now I need a solution. I can't think of any off the top of my head

Comment: @MathEnthusiastThatsBadAtMath -- Implement the rule of 3, as stated in my first comment.  Then rewrite the assignment operator using [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).  Even if you added the `delete[]` line, your assignment operator has the flaw of deleting the data before the call to `new[]` is invoked.  What if `new[]` throws and exception?  You would have corrupted the object by deleting the data prematurely.  That's what copy/swap prevents from occurring.

Comment: `new tribool(DELIM)` allocates a single instance of `tribool`, and should eventually be matched with `delete tribool` (without square brackets). `new tribool[2]` allocates an array of two elements, and should eventually be matched with `delete[] triboolList` (with square brackets). Either you should avoid doing this - using a single object form of `new` sometimes and array form other times - or you should keep track of which form you last used, so you can match it with an appropriate form of `delete`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the class has a destructor and a copy constructor, I will add the copy assignment operator and will tell you if that fixes the issue

Comment: @MathEnthusiastThatsBadAtMath -- As long as the copy constructor does not call the assignment operator, it works correctly (with the destructor working also), then copy/swap is a foolproof way of implementing the assignment operator.  Also, you should be returning `Binary&` from the assignment operator, and not really `void`.

Comment: Here is my Copy Constructor:
```
Binary::Binary(const Binary& copyBinary) {

    triboolList = new tribool[triLength(copyBinary.triboolList) + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) triLength(copyBinary.triboolList); i++) {
        triboolList[i] = (const tribool)copyBinary.triboolList[i];
    }
    triboolList[triLength(copyBinary.triboolList)] = DELIM;

}
```

Comment: Please post the code in the original question, not in the comments.  Second, does the passed-in `copyBinary` have as its `triboolList` the value of `DELIM` at that particular array position?  If not, then you are introducing a side-effect, where you are not copying the object that was passed-in.  Side-effects introduced in the basic copy/assignment operations should be avoided, as these turn into one of the toughest bugs to find.

Comment: Yup, all of the other constructors and assignment operators add a DELIM to the end of the triboolList

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I put the code in the original question

Comment: Your assignment operator does not check for self assignment, thus the `delete[]` will be wrong, and still will cause a double-delete error in other situations.  But as already stated, copy/swap solves all of these issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I can't use std::copy or std::swap as they are not compatible with the Arduino IDE

Comment: You didn't read the copy/swap article carefully.  There is no `std::copy` being done, plus `std::swap` is nothing more than exchanging the two items.  It is just that `std::swap` is a convenient function to do the exchange.

Comment: So is the copy constructor and copy assignment operator the copy part of the copy-swap idiom?

Comment: The copy constructor and the destructor are the parts that must work correctly.  In addition, the copy constructor cannot call the assignment operator in any way.  Once you have the copy constructor and destructor working, the copy/swap is used to implement the assignment operator easily, since it uses the copy constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment operator does not check for self-assignment, plus will have a double-free error since you are simply copying the pointer value between objects.

Instead of this, the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) can be used.

Since you state that Arduino does not have `std::swap`, it should be easily implemented using the following:

```
Binary& Binary::operator=(Binary copyBinary) 
{ 
   tribool* temp = triboolList;
   triboolList = copyBinary.triboolList;
   copyBinary.triboolList = temp;
   return *this;
}
```

This should be equivalent to the following, if `std::swap` existed:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Binary& Binary::operator=(Binary copyBinary) 
{ 
   std::swap(triboolList, copyBinary.triboolList);
   return *this;
}
```

If there are member variables other than `triboolList`, they also have to be swapped with the passed-in members.  I am assuming that `triboolList` is the only member variable.

Comment: Yup, it works! triboolList is the only member variable. I am going to test it with other constructors and see if it works

Comment: It works with other constructors to. It works with Default, Unsigned int Parameterized, and Array Parameterized. Thank you!